# Numpy multiplying different shapes

Tags: python, numpy

have two arrays that are like this

```
x = [a,b]
y = [p,q,r]
```

I need to multiply this together to a product `c` which should be like this,

```
c = [a*p, a*q, a*r, b*p, b*q, b*r]
```

However `x*y` gives the following error,

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)
```

I can do something like this,

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    for t in range(len(y)):
        c.append(x[i] * y[t]
```

But really the length of my `x` and `y` is quite large so what's the most efficient way to make such a multiplication without the looping.

Comment: Where `a`, `b`, `p`, `q` etc are scalars or something else?

Comment: @Divakar they are floats so I suppose they are scalars isn't it?

Comment: It seems that you've missed `a*r`

Comment: @Kasramvd edited :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for pairwise elementwise multiplication between `x` and `y` and then flatten with `.ravel()`, like so -

```
(x[:,None]*y).ravel()
```

Or use [`outer product`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) and then flatten -

```
np.outer(x,y).ravel()
```

Comment: Thanks, also how can I make the output like this `c = [[a*p, a*q, a*r], [b*p, b*q, b*r]]`

Comment: @rksh Use without flattening, i.e. without using `.ravel()`?

Comment: Yes without the flattening :)

Comment: or d = np.einsum('ij, ij -> ij', a[:,None], b[None]) ... a[:,None].shape -> (2, 1), 
and  ... b[None].shape -> (1, 3)

Comment: @DanPatterson Yup the versatile einsum! Probably overkill here, but an alternative!

Comment: @DanPatterson what about using the numpy dot function mentioned in the below answer what's the better option?

Comment: @rksh mine was purely a comment.  It is a versatile function, but often left off the list of alternatives for problem solving.

Comment: @rksh We are performing elementwise multiplication without any reduction, so `np.dot` won't give you any benefit.

Comment: @Divakar Does `None` offer any benefits over `np.newaxis` ?

Comment: @KolaB Nope, both are the same. None is simply an alias here for np.newaxis.

Answer (score 0):

Use Numpy dot...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.arange(1,3)# [1,2]
>>> b=np.arange(1,4)# [1,2,3]
>>> np.dot(a[:,None],b[None])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6]])
>>> np.dot(a[:,None],b[None]).ravel()
array([1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6])
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks what about the same function without the flattening?