# Multiplication of two matrices of different size numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I want to multiply two matrices :

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = np.array([[2,3,4],[5,6,7]])

a
array([[1, 2],
   [3, 4]])
b
array([[2, 3, 4],
   [5, 6, 7]])
```

I want result something like:

```
array([[2,4,3,6,4,8],[15,20,18,24,21,28]])
```

How can I do it using numpy?

Need help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the result you want: it is `[5,6,7]` multiplied by `[2,3]` consecutively? Or am I misunderstanding....

Comment: Explain the desired result.  There are various ways of multiplying a (2,2) with a (2,3).  But producing a (2,6) isn't entirely obvious.

Comment: This isn't a matrix multiplication! Why don't you tell us what kind of operator you are trying to calculate?

Comment: There was a small mistake in the desired result. I edited it now. So I want to do something like multiply each element of b with each element of a row wise to get all possible combinations.

Comment: Its like multiplying `[2,3,4]` with `[1,2]` to get `[2,4,3,6,4,8]`

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39026173/numpy-multiplying-different-shapes).

You can use [numpy broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) or use the [outer product](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html).

```
a[:,:,None]*b
```

or

```
np.outer(a,b)
```

Comment: I am still not able to get the desired result.

Comment: The link where it solves similar issue is good when it is just one dimensional. But not for example in my case.